# Is the punctuation in this phrase correct?

Tags: phrases

Is the punctuation in this phrase correct?
...like two, li'l, sweet "peas in a pod"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given that 'peas in a pod' is such a well-known idiom, I don't think it needs quotes.
2. I would write "two little sweet peas" and so I would likewise write "two l'il sweet peas"

So my solution would be:

*...like two li'l sweet peas in a pod!*

Answer (score 1):

No comma between "two" and "li'l'" because one would not say or write "two and li'l."

Comment: could you explain further?